# GLSL for-loop array index

Tags: opengl, glsl, intel

I'm having some trouble using variable indices in GLSL.
The folowing GLSL code is working fine on NVidia cards. But its not working on my Intel HD 4000:

```
for(int i=0;i<int(uLightCount);++i)
{
    vec3 lightPos = uLightsPos[i];
    ....
}
```

There is no Shader-Compiler Error. The program simply crashes on `glUseProgram`

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

`uLightCount` and `uLightsPos` are uniforms:

```
#define MAX_LIGHTS 10
uniform float uLightCount;
uniform vec3 uLightsPos[MAX_LIGHTS];
```

**Edit 2:**

I have found a strange workaround:

```
#define i0  0
#define i1  1
#define i2  2
...

for(int i=0;i<int(uLightCount);++i)
{
    vec3 lightPos;

    if (i==i0) 
        lightPos = uLightsPos[i0];
    if (i==i1) 
        lightPos = uLightsPos[i1];
    ....
}
```

Any idea why this is working?

Comment: May be you should check what shader model is supported by Intel cards?Usually these are onboard cards supporting very old OpenGL and GLSL implementations

Comment: with the latest bootcamp driver (on my MacBook Air) OpenGL 4.0 is supported

Comment: Tried to read glGetError() ?

Comment: Yes but no error. I have a error check after each gl-call.

Comment: And you say it works if you unroll the loop ?

Comment: What `#version` are you targeting?

Comment: I tried a lot of versions. Currently I'm using `#version 330`. It seems that the version does not matter

Comment: If you run the same shader on the Mac OS side, does it have any problems?

Comment: on OSX the shader is working fine. I also tried this shader on a Surface Pro (with the same HD 4000) -> same error

Comment: How are `uLightCount` and `uLightsPos` declared?

Comment: Like this: 
`#define MAX_LIGHTS 10`
`uniform float uLightCount;`
`uniform vec3 uLightsPos[MAX_LIGHTS];`

Comment: your loop works fine on my Intel HD 4000. Please show us whole shader. Which driver version do you use?

Comment: I have found out that the problem only occures in combination with other shaders (while switching from a working shader with no loops to this one) and 64bit. 32Bit is working fine. Driver Version is 9.17.10.2932 on Windows 8. To post the whole shader/s would be a bit to much code

Comment: Maybe try the latest driver 15.31.3.3071 (9.17.10.3071). You will find it [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Desktop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=3rd+Generation+Intel%c2%ae+Core%e2%84%a2+Processors+with+Intel%c2%ae+HD+Graphics+4000%2f2500).

Comment: I tried the new driver version. Same problem. :(

Comment: Try updating drivers to most recent 15.33 version.

Comment: The 15.33 driver solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The index must be constant. That's why your workaround works.

So it's not possible to write that

```
for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
{
  result += uLightsPos[i];
}
```

Comment: No, modern cards support both dynamic branching and loops. Contrary to what many say, depending on the application and thread divergence the overhead can also be small. `glUseProgram` shouldn't crash. This was a driver bug.

Comment: I should qualify the above by saying too that in many cases, unrolling loops by supplying compile time constants as in the answer can allow the compiler to make lots of optimizations.

Comment: hmm, I had this issue recently with GLSL on WebGL. Not a crash, but the shader compilation failed. Actually my code was more like that (and maybe you can give me an advice): `void func () { for(int i=0;i<10;++i) { func2 (i); }}` `void func2 (int index) { float value = myArray [index]; ... }`

Comment: aah yes, you're right, webgl is quite limited there. in this case with [dynamic indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247572/variable-array-index-not-possible-in-webgl-shaders). A pattern such as `for (int i = 0; i < n && i < MAX_N; ++i)` gives a dynamic bound and allows the compiler to unroll (to nested if-statements). Still, different drivers/the glsl compiler can be confused easily and sometimes its better to just unroll manually. Macros really help there.

Comment: At the end, I've created a template system to generate dynamically the shader. That works fine.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Looping over a uniform array was possible even back in GLSL 1.20, let alone 4.x+. The OP is clearly encountering a driver bug.

Comment: @Bram: Then you have done something wrong or you have encountered a driver bug. There is nothing in [this document](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.50.pdf) which disallows non-constant array indexing of uniform arrays.

Comment: @NicolBolas my issue was with input array written by vertex shader, read by fragment shader. Not a uniform array,

Comment: @Bram: I don't see the part of that document which disallows non-constant array indexing of *input* arrays either.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, I have done this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    int j = i;
    and use myArray[j];
}
```

It compiled... so you can try in your code.

Comment: everything compiles, it just doesn't work ...

Comment: in my case, the issue was making a uniform int from a float, which resulted in the value being a zero