# generating a texture to pull values from during fragment shading yields blank screen for correct width and height

Tags: javascript, graphics, glsl, webgl, shader

I would like to create a texture in code consisting of an array of RGBA color values and use those values to determine the colors of tiles that I'm generating in a fragment shader. I got the idea, and much of the code to do this from the top solution provided to this SO question: [Index expression must be constant - WebGL/GLSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529690/index-expression-must-be-constant-webgl-glsl-error)

However, if I create the texture using the height and width that correspond to my color array, I don't see anything render to the canvas. If I hardcode different values, I sometimes get an image, but that image doesn't place the tile colors in the desired positions, of course, and they move around as I change my viewPos variables.

From trial and error testing with a handful of handpicked values, it seems that I MIGHT only be getting an image when gl.texImage2D() receives a height and a width equal to a power of 2, though I don't see anything about this in documentation. 32 was the largest width I could produce an image with, and 16 was the largest height I could produce an image with. 1, 2, 4, and 8 also work. (the texture size *should* be 27 by 20 for the window size I'm testing with)

Note that the fragment shader still receives the uTileColorSampSize vector that relates to the size of the color array. I only need the gl.texImage2D() width and height values to be hardcoded to produce an image. In fact, every value i've tried for the uniform has produced an image, though each with different tile color patterns.

I've included a slightly simplified version of my Gfx class (the original is kinda messy, and includes a lot of stuff not relevant to this issue) below. I'd imagine the problem is above like 186 or so, but I've included a few additional functions below that in case those happen to be relevant.

```
class Gfx {
    constructor() {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        this.gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

        //viewPos changes as you drag your cursor across the canvas
        this.x_viewPos = 0;
        this.y_viewPos = 0;
    }
    init() {
        this.resizeCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        const vsSource = `
            attribute vec4 aVertPos;

            uniform mat4 uMVMat;
            uniform mat4 uProjMat;

            void main() {
                gl_Position = uProjMat * uMVMat * aVertPos;
            }
        `;

        //my tiles get drawn in the frag shader below
        const fsSource = `
            precision mediump float;

            uniform vec2 uViewPos;
            uniform vec2 uTileColorSampSize;
            uniform sampler2D uTileColorSamp;

            void main() {
                //tile width and height are both 33px including a 1px border
                const float lineThickness = (1.0/33.0);

                //gridMult components will either be 0.0 or 1.0. This is used to place the grid lines
                vec2 gridMult = vec2(
                    ceil(max(0.0, fract((gl_FragCoord.x-uViewPos.x)/33.0) - lineThickness)),
                    ceil(max(0.0, fract((gl_FragCoord.y-uViewPos.y)/33.0) - lineThickness))
                );
                //tileIndex is used to pull color data from the sampler texture
                //add 0.5 due to pixel coords being off in gl
                vec2 tileIndex = vec2(
                    floor((gl_FragCoord.x-uViewPos.x)/33.0) + 0.5, 
                    floor((gl_FragCoord.y-uViewPos.y)/33.0) + 0.5
                );

                //divide by samp size as tex coords are 0.0 to 1.0
                vec4 tileColor = texture2D(uTileColorSamp, vec2(
                    tileIndex.x/uTileColorSampSize.x,
                    tileIndex.y/uTileColorSampSize.y
                ));

                gl_FragColor = vec4(
                    tileColor.x * gridMult.x * gridMult.y,
                    tileColor.y * gridMult.x * gridMult.y,
                    tileColor.z * gridMult.x * gridMult.y,
                    1.0 //the 4th rgba in our sampler is always 1.0 anyway
                );
            }
        `;

        const shader = this.buildShader(vsSource, fsSource);
        this.programInfo = {
            program: shader,
            attribLocs: {
                vertexPosition: this.gl.getAttribLocation(shader, 'aVertPos')
            },
            uniformLocs: {
                projMat: this.gl.getUniformLocation(shader, 'uProjMat'),
                MVMat: this.gl.getUniformLocation(shader, 'uMVMat'),
                viewPos: this.gl.getUniformLocation(shader, 'uViewPos'),
                tileColorSamp: this.gl.getUniformLocation(shader, 'uTileColorSamp'),
                tileColorSampSize: this.gl.getUniformLocation(shader, 'uTileColorSampSize')
            }
        };
        const buffers = this.initBuffers();

        //check and enable OES_texture_float to allow us to create our sampler tex
        if (!this.gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float")) {
            alert("Sorry, your browser/GPU/driver doesn't support floating point textures");
        }

        this.gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.15, 1.0);
        this.gl.clearDepth(1.0);
        this.gl.enable(this.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        this.gl.depthFunc(this.gl.LEQUAL);

        const FOV = 45 * Math.PI / 180;   // in radians
        const aspect = this.gl.canvas.width / this.gl.canvas.height;
        this.projMat = glMatrix.mat4.create();
        glMatrix.mat4.perspective(this.projMat, FOV, aspect, 0.0, 100.0);
        this.MVMat = glMatrix.mat4.create();
        glMatrix.mat4.translate(this.MVMat, this.MVMat, [-0.0, -0.0, -1.0]);

        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
        this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.programInfo.attribLocs.vertPos, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.programInfo.attribLocs.vertPos);

        this.glDraw();
    }
    //glDraw() gets called once above, as well as in every frame of my render loop
    //(not included here as I have it in a seperate Timing class)
    glDraw() {
        this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        this.gl.useProgram(this.programInfo.program);

        //X and Y TILE_COUNTs varrified to correspond to colorArray size in testing
        //(colorArray.length = rgbaLength * X_TILE_COUNT * Y_TILE_COUNT)
        //(colorArray.length = rgbaLength * widthInTiles * heightInTiles)
        //(colorArray.length = 4 * 27 * 20)
        let x_tileColorSampSize = X_TILE_COUNT; 
        let y_tileColorSampSize = Y_TILE_COUNT;

        //getTileColorArray() produces a flat array of floats between 0.0and 1.0
        //equal in length to rgbaLength * X_TILE_COUNT * Y_TILE_COUNT
        //every 4th value is 1.0, representing tile alpha
        let colorArray = this.getTileColorArray();

        let colorTex = this.colorMapTexFromArray(
            x_tileColorSampSize,
            y_tileColorSampSize,
            colorArray
        );
        //SO solution said to use anyting between 0 and 15 for texUnit, they used 3
        //I imagine this is just an arbitrary location in memory to hold a texture 
        let texUnit = 3;
        this.gl.activeTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE0 + texUnit);
        this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, colorTex);
        this.gl.uniform1i(
            this.programInfo.uniformLocs.tileColorSamp,
            texUnit
        );
        this.gl.uniform2fv(
            this.programInfo.uniformLocs.tileColorSampSize,
            [x_tileColorSampSize, y_tileColorSampSize]
        );
        this.gl.uniform2fv(
            this.programInfo.uniformLocs.viewPos,
            [-this.x_viewPos, this.y_viewPos] //these change as you drag your cursor across the canvas
        );

        this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
            this.programInfo.uniformLocs.projMat,
            false,
            this.projMat
        );
        this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
            this.programInfo.uniformLocs.MVMat,
            false,
            this.MVMat
        );

        this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
    colorMapTexFromArray(width, height, colorArray) {
        let float32Arr = Float32Array.from(colorArray);
        let oldActive = this.gl.getParameter(this.gl.ACTIVE_TEXTURE);
        //SO solution said "working register 31, thanks", next to next line
        //not sure what that means but I think they're just looking for any
        //arbitrary place to store the texture?
        this.gl.activeTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE15);  

        var texture = this.gl.createTexture();
        this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        this.gl.texImage2D(
            this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGBA,
            //if I replace width and height with certain magic numbers
            //like 4 or 8 (all the way up to 32 for width and 16 for height)
            //I will see colored tiles, though obviously they don't map correctly.
            //I THINK I've only seen it work with a widths and heights that are
            //a power of 2... could the issue be that I need my texture to have
            //width and height equal to a power of 2?
            width, height, 0,
            this.gl.RGBA, this.gl.FLOAT, float32Arr
        );

        //use gl.NEAREST to prevent gl from blurring texture
        this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, this.gl.NEAREST);
        this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this.gl.NEAREST);


        this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
        this.gl.activeTexture(oldActive);

        return texture;
    }

    //I don't think the issue would be in the functions below, but I included them anyway
    resizeCanvas(baseWidth, baseHeight) {
        let widthMod = 0;
        let heightMod = 0;
        //...some math is done here to account for some DOM elements that consume window space...
        this.canvas.width = baseWidth + widthMod;
        this.canvas.height = baseHeight + heightMod;
        this.gl.viewport(0, 0, this.gl.canvas.width, this.gl.canvas.height);
    }
    initBuffers() {
        const posBuff = this.gl.createBuffer();
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBuff);
        const positions = [
            -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,
        ];
        this.gl.bufferData(
            this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
            new Float32Array(positions),
            this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
        );
        return {
            position: posBuff
        };
    }
    buildShader(vsSource, fsSource) {
        const vertShader = this.loadShader(this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
        const fragShader = this.loadShader(this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);

        const shaderProg = this.gl.createProgram();
        this.gl.attachShader(shaderProg, vertShader);
        this.gl.attachShader(shaderProg, fragShader);
        this.gl.linkProgram(shaderProg);

        if (!this.gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProg, this.gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            console.error('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProg));
            return null;
        }

        return shaderProg;
    }
    loadShader(type, source) {
        const shader = this.gl.createShader(type);      
        this.gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
        this.gl.compileShader(shader);

        if (!this.gl.getShaderParameter(shader, this.gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.error('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + this.gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            this.gl.deleteShader(shader);
            return null;
        }
        return shader;
    }

    //getTileColorArray as it appears in my code, in case you want to take a peak.
    //every tileGrid[i][j] has a color, which is an array of 4 values between 0.0 and 1.0
    //the fourth (last) value in tileGrid[i][j].color is always 1.0
    getTileColorArray() {
        let i_min = Math.max(0, Math.floor(this.x_pxPosToTilePos(this.x_viewPos)));
        let i_max = Math.min(GLOBAL.map.worldWidth-1, i_min + Math.ceil(this.x_pxPosToTilePos(this.canvas.width)) + 1);
        let j_min = Math.max(0, Math.floor(this.y_pxPosToTilePos(this.y_viewPos)));
        let j_max = Math.min(GLOBAL.map.worldHeight-1, j_min + Math.ceil(this.y_pxPosToTilePos(this.canvas.height)) + 1);

        let colorArray = [];
        for (let i=i_min; i <= i_max; i++) {
            for (let j=j_min; j <= j_max; j++) {
                colorArray = colorArray.concat(GLOBAL.map.tileGrid[i][j].color);
            }
        }
        return colorArray;
    }
}
```

I've also included a pastebin of my full unaltered Gfx class in case you would like to look at that as well: https://pastebin.com/f0erR9qG

And a pastebin of my simplified code for the line numbers: https://pastebin.com/iB1pUZJa

Answer (score 0):

WebGL 1.0 does not support texture wrapping on textures with non-power of two dimensions. There are two ways to solve this issue, one is to buffer the texture with enough extra data to make it have power of two dimensions, and the other solution it to simply turn off texture wrapping, like so:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I'm still getting strange behavior in my frag shader, but its at least showing tiles now. I think the additional strange behavior is just a result of my shader algorithm not matching what I have envisioned.